# jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js difference between themes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, themes

Does the jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js file included with the themes you download from jqueryui.com differ from theme to theme, or is it the same?

Edit:
I'm trying out different themes to see which one looks best for the site.  I have the following folders:

```
/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js

/jquery/css/sunny/images/
/jquery/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css

/jquery/css/dot-luv/images/
/jquery/css/dot-luv/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css
```

The first two would always remain the same but would change between the sunny and the dot-luv themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme selection will not have any influence on the file size of the jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js file (I've checked three packages; two preset themes and a custom theme: the javascript file was 206.991 bytes in all versions).

The JQuery UI theme is determined entirely by its images and CSS file. Therefore, your choice will result in different images and a different CSS file.

The JQuery UI downloader allows you to choose different parts of JQuery UI to include. The choices you make there will result in differences in the jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js file, as well as differences in the included images and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It should differ (at least among custom themes).  Or are you talking about among preset themes?

Comment: I'm referring to the themes like ui-lightness, sunny, vader, etc.